# connecting to a unicode-encoded sqlite3 database path

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

When I try to connect to a sqlite3 database in Python using a unicode path string, the entire path string is misinterpreted as the database name:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2015, 06:14:37)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(u'my.db')
>>> exit()
$ ls -lt | head -n 2
total 554000
-rw-r--r-- 1 shahin users         0 Nov 14 01:11 ????????b
```

I'm not able to replicate it on other machines. This doesn't happen when I:

- pass ascii paths to `sqlite3.connect`, or
- pass unicode paths to Python's `open`

Why is the `sqlite3` library misinterpreting my path as a nonsense file name?

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.8.8 2015-01-16 12:08:06 7d68a42face3ab14ed88407d4331872f5b243fdf
```

Comment: This is a SQLite C library problem. Python Unicode objects get [encoded to UTF-8](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#l97) and passed to [`sqlite3_open()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), which expects UTF-8. This is not a Python issue therefor.